# AS3 and Youtube API default Youtube buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

This seems like a simple enough question, I have some straight-forward AS3 to load a video from Youtube, using the Youtube API. That's working just fine, however I expect the default Youtube player controls to show up, and they don't seem to be. I see how to toggle them on via HTML, but I need them to be toggled on via the AS3 as I can't edit the HTML Embed or IFrame tags. Here is my code so far:

```
   import flash.display.Loader;
   import flash.net.URLRequest;
   import flash.events.Event;
   import flash.system.Security;

   Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
   Security.allowInsecureDomain("www.youtube.com");

   var vid_player:Object;

   var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
   my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
   my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

   function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void{
    addChild(my_loader);
    vid_player = my_loader.content;
    vid_player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
   }

   function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
     vid_player.setSize(415,234);
     vid_player.loadVideoById("sq7wu4OukBE",0);
   }
```

So this pulls it right in, but if you rollover the controls don't toggle up. I'd also like the video paused, until a user presses play, however this code above autoplays. I did come up with a setting that will show the video paused at first, however it just pulls in a large version of the video and doesn't let me size it:

```
   loadVideoById({'videoId': 'bHQqvYy5KYo', 'startSeconds': 5, 'endSeconds': 60,  'suggestedQuality': 'large'});
```

adjusting suggestedQuality doesn't change dimensions just resolution. Any clarity to both questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the default player with controls use this url:

http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3

Replace VIDEO_ID with the ID of your video.

Here's a good reference of all the available settings and API calls.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Playback_controls

Comment: Thanks for that - however changing it to "2" makes it go super large and ignore my size settings. I did see your example earlier but didn't seem to function - since I have my code functioning I'd like to stick with but just need those darn default controls. :)

Comment: also, replacing: loadVideoById with cueVideoById pulls the video in super large as well. Anyway if anyone sees a solution let me know!

Comment: well I know for sure you will never get controls with player 3.  You could however, create your own.

Comment: that's true - are you sure version=2 isn't for actionscript 2?

Comment: That may be.  Just edited my answer with what I think should solve your issue.  Tested it with my own player build and I get controls.

Comment: for more detailed result I receive this: *** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'https://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/apiplayer-vfl8vTam0.swf' tried to access incompatible context 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/apiplayer?version=2' when updating to version 2

Comment: dont use  version 2.  Use the updated code I have in my answer.  Player version 3, but with a different url call than the one you are using in your original post.

Comment: I actually figured that part out on my own from the Google Developers reference - it's very specific isn't it? Anyway, I have a new question now perhaps you can help with, visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966976/youtube-api-actionscript-3-and-thumbnails