# Youtube API Actionscript 3 and Thumbnails

Tags: actionscript-3, api, youtube, youtube-api, video-thumbnails

I've got the Youtube API setup in AS3 - it's all loading nicely but I'd like to load multiple thumbnails and then display them so that user may click one to watch the video but I'm having a little trouble doing this.

The code that I have for doing this is this: (where "vid_player" is the instance name of my container object.

```
   function createFeaturedButtons(vid_player:Object, featuredVideos:Array) {
   var results:Array = [];
   for each (var id:String in featuredVideos) {
    results.push(vid_player.getClickToPlayButton("BYjoERBzfNw"));
results.push(vid_player.getClickToPlayButton("oEB50roGOOg"));
    }
    return results;
   }
```

Now how do I get it to display my results of my Array?

Comment: for more reference to my code view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926908/as3-and-youtube-api-default-youtube-buttons  I've got the default buttons showing now however using: http://www.youtube.com/v/ID?version=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the thumbnails and add them to the stage display list in a row with 5 pixels between each.  The number of items in idArray defines how many buttons will load:

```
var spacing:Number = 5;
var nextX:Number = 0;
var idArray:Array = [ 'BYjoERBzfNw', 'oEB50roGOOg', 'oEB50roGOOg', 'oEB50roGOOg', 'oEB50roGOOg' ];

// this call needs to be made in the onPlayerReady() method (not listed in this example but part of the youtube player initialization process)
createThumbnails( vid_player, idArray );

function createThumbnails( vid_player:Object, videoIdArray:Array )
{
    var i:int;
    var results:Array = [];

    for( i = 0; i < videoIdArray.length; i++ )
    {
        results.push( vid_player.getClickToPlayButton( videoIdArray[ i ] ) );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < results.length; i ++ )
    {
        // set whatever width and height you want the thumb to be
        results[ i ].width = 50;
        results[ i ].height = 50;

        // set its position
        results[ i ].x = nextX;
        // set the next position
        nextX += results[ i ].width + spacing;

        addChild( results[ i ] );
    }
}
```

the output from this routine, when added to code that successfully loads a player, (using my own video IDs) looks like below, (I used the same ID for all 5 thumbs):

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could clarify a bit? This produces an error: Access of undefined property idArray (also I assume I switch in an actual "id" for this line: results.push( vid_player.getClickToPlayButton(id));  )

Comment: Ok so I got the error to be eliminated by adding: var idArray:Array; at the top of my code - however I still see no thumbnails. I feel like I'm just missing something small here - really appreciate your help so far!!

Comment: I presumed you had collected your video IDs in an array.  You need to pass createFeaturedButtons() an array of video IDs as the second argument.  I changed the createButtons loop as well.  See the code edit.

Comment: Thanks! This is so close but still getting a: (see linked thread for the rest of my code) TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at youtube_api_fla::MainTimeline/createThumbnails()
 at youtube_api_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: any more suggestions? :)

Comment: Not sure what else to tell ya bud, I posted a pic of the results of the code.  It works.

Comment: Yeah I just get that same error - not sure what is wrong - I directly copy and paste the code to my file - even commenting out any old code I may have and nothing just the error that I list above

Comment: Here is my entire code: http://codebin.org/view/3dc43164 is there a conflict in there somewhere?

Comment: Took me a sec but I think I found your problem.  The null object reference is the player.  You are calling createThumbnails(vid_player, idArray) before the player is created.  Move that line into the onPlayerReady() function as the last line of that function.

Comment: Also, just something to note:  the size of the thumbnails being set to 50x50 should be changed to represent the aspect ratio of your video, otherwise the images may look squished.

Comment: Rock n Roll! That did it! Thank you so much! My next mission is to create the thumbnails not within the youtube video but next to it.. haha..

Comment: That's easy, instead of addChild( results[ i ] ), just say someThumbnailContainer.addChild( results[ i ] );  Then position that container.  glad you got it working!  :)

Comment: If you set "Permit Debugging" in the Publish settings window you can see what line number the error occurred on.  My guess is that the container you created to hold the thumbnails doesn't exist when createThumbnails() is called, or you are not pathing to it correctly.  Start at the top of createThumbnails() and trace each thing in the function one at a time until you find out what's null.